# Alternative to creating a stack of modal UIViewControllers?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I have a situation where a user progresses through a series of "levels".  Each level has it's own UIViewController.  Right now, I simply present the next level like this:

```
// in level 1 view controller, for example, here's how we go to level 2
[self presentModalViewController:level2VC animated:YES];
```

This is nice and easy, but obviously it results in a really large stack of UIViewControllers.  Ideally, I'd like to do a nice visual transition (like cross-dissolve) to the next level's UIViewController and then **release** the last one to conserve memory, but I think that'll cause instability since I'd be releasing the parent view controller in this approach.

What is the best approach then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is what a UINavigationController was built for! [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: But wouldn't I still be creating a growing stack of UIViewControllers in that case if I use pushViewController?

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationController` is the common idiom for the kind of UI you are describing.

You push a new view controller by executing: `pushViewController:animated:`, which also provides for the transition effect you are looking for.

Keep in mind, anyway, that this is meant exactly for  "navigating" : i.e., moving back and forth. So, it is not just going forward, unless you customize the navigation bar by hiding the "back" button `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES]`.

Furthermore, all the `UIViewController`a are kept in memory (always) and only in case of low memory conditions (`-[didReceiveMemoryWarning][1]`) the "controlled" views will be automatically released, thus recovering memory. If this happens, you will need to ensure you are able to load again the views in case the user navigates back.

If you are really concerned about memory (although I think that it should not be a problem), you could even think of "poppping" (i.e., removing) the current controller, before pushing the next one. This would endure a very "flat" hierarchy of controllers.